# Signals below trigger level are still captured by the oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, trigger

I use NI's oscilloscope PXIE-5162 to measure the Na-22 spectrum with Canberra's NaI(TI) photomultiplier tube. I notice that although the trigger level is always kept constant at 0.1V, there are still some data below the threshold captured by the oscilloscope. As you can see from the region circled, the blue and black histograms had a few events lower than 0.1V recorded. Why does this happen?

Note: The black histogram represents the PMT exposed to no source, the blue histogram represents the PMT exposed to Na-22 placed 5cm away from it and the red histogram represents the source placed directly on top of the PMT.[image: na-22 spectrum]

Comment: Is your oscilloscope trigger set to **NORMAL** or to **AUTO**? Likely should be NORMAL

Comment: The effective bandwidth of the trigger circuit can be higher than the effective capture bandwidth. So, you had a narrow pulse trigger the scope, but it wasn't captured.

Comment: Your histogram has some levels below the trigger level. Is that not expected?  Does your plot show signal level on the X axis and some sort of normalized occurrence on the y?

Comment: The trigger level is only the *trigger threshold*. It is not the *measurement threshold*. If the trigger threshold is reached then the scope will start recording. If the signal drops below the trigger threshold while it's recording then that's just what will be recorded.